# add extra content into exported excel sheet in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, export-to-excel

I am exporting the selected items in gridview to excel. Now the exported excel should contain something like "Excel downloaded on: TODAY_DATE" (where TODAY_DATE is today's date in mm/dd/yyyy format).

My Question: How can i append the text (as mentioned above) in the exported excel?

Thanks!

Comment: how you are exporting? i.e. by using interop or any third party library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same can be done through html.writer("Content Comes here!").

The above solution is valid only if an excel sheet is generated from HTML.